# using memcpy for copy constructor and assignment operator for 2d array

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, memcpy, assignment-operator

I have 2 classes.
Pointer to an array of fixed width and Pointer to a Pointer for implementing 2d array of floats.
I wanted to understand, if and how can I use memcpy for my Copy constructor and Assignment operator overload.

```
class UsingPtrToArr {
  public:
    UsingPtrToArr() {
      m_rows = 1;
      f = new float[m_rows][8];
      for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
      {
        f[0][i] = i+1;
      }
    }
    UsingPtrToArr(const UsingPtrToArr& iv) {
      m_rows = iv.m_rows;
      f = new float[m_rows][8];
      for(int r = 0; r < m_rows; ++r) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
          f[r][i] = iv.f[r][i];
      }
      sum = iv.sum;
    }
    UsingPtrToArr& operator= (const UsingPtrToArr& iv) {
      m_rows = iv.m_rows;
      f = new float[m_rows][8];
      for(int r = 0; r < m_rows; ++r) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
          f[r][i] = iv.f[r][i];
      }
      sum = iv.sum;
      return *this;
    }
    void sumArray() {
      for(int r = 0; r < m_rows; ++r) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
          sum += f[r][i];
      }
    }

    ~UsingPtrToArr() {
      delete[] f;
    }
  private:
    float (*f)[8];
    double sum = 0;
    int m_rows;
};
```

another class

```
class UsingPtrToPtr {
  public:
    UsingPtrToPtr() {
      int row = 1;
      int col = 8;
      m_rows = row;
      m_cols = col;
      f = new float*[row];
      for(int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
        f[i] = new float[col];
      }
      for (int i = 1; i < row; ++i)
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j) {
          f[i][j] = j+1;
        }
      }
    }
    UsingPtrToPtr(const UsingPtrToPtr& iv) {
      sum = iv.sum;
      m_rows = iv.m_rows;
      m_cols = iv.m_cols;
      f = new float*[m_rows];
      for(int i = 0; i < m_rows; ++i) {
        f[i] = new float[m_cols];
      }
      for (int i = 1; i < m_rows; ++i)
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < m_cols; ++j) {
          f[i][j] = iv.f[i][j];
        }
      }
      sum = iv.sum;
    }
    UsingPtrToPtr& operator= (const UsingPtrToPtr& iv) {
      m_rows = iv.m_rows;
      m_cols = iv.m_cols;
      f = new float*[m_rows];
      for(int i = 0; i < m_rows; ++i) {
        f[i] = new float[m_cols];
      }
      for (int i = 1; i < m_rows; ++i)
      {
        std::memcpy(f[i], iv.f[i], sizeof(float) * m_cols);
        for (int j = 0; j < m_cols; ++j) {
          f[i][j] = iv.f[i][j];
        }
      }
      sum = iv.sum;
      return *this;
    }
    void sumArray() {
      for (int i = 1; i < m_rows; ++i)
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < m_cols; ++j) {
          sum += f[i][j];
        }
      }
    }
    ~UsingPtrToPtr() {
      for (int i = 1; i < m_rows; ++i)
      {
        delete[] f[i];
      }
      delete[] f;
    }
  private:
    float **f;
    int m_rows;
    int m_cols;
    double sum = 0;
};
```

Disclaimer: This for my understanding purpose. I know, I can use `std::vector` in C++.

Comment: What do these classes suppose to do? The loop through `f[0][i-1] = i;` leaves `f[0][7]` uninitialized.

Comment: *This for my understanding purpose. I know, I can use `std::vector` in C++.* For over a decade, because of smart object managers like `std::vector` and `std::unique_ptr`, I have not used (nor needed to use) `new` or `delete` in a real program.

Comment: @273K corrected it.

Comment: There are memory leaks in both of those `operator=` implementations.  Instead of doing all of this work in `operator=`, all it takes to get it correct is [copy and swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom).  For example: `UsingPtrToPtr& operator= (const UsingPtrToPtr iv) { std::swap(f, iv.f); std::swap(sum, iv.sum); std::swap(m_rows, iv.m_rows); std::swap(m_cols, iv.m_cols); return *this; }`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie We probably shouldn't attempt to modify the `const UsingPtrToPtr&` passed into the copy assignment operator.

Comment: That should be `(UsingPtrToPtr iv)` and not `const`.

Comment: Regardless of whether the prototype can be messed with or not, copy-and-swap is a great alternative to be aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code seems to work

```
UsingPtrToArr(const UsingPtrToArr& iv) {
      m_rows = iv.m_rows;
      f = new float[m_rows][8];
      std::memcpy(f, iv.f, sizeof(float)*m_rows*8);
      sum = iv.sum;
}
```

and for UsingPtrToPtr, I used the below code

```
    UsingPtrToPtr(const UsingPtrToPtr& iv) {
          sum = iv.sum;
          m_rows = iv.m_rows;
          m_cols = iv.m_cols;
          f = new float*[m_rows];
          for(int i = 0; i < m_rows; ++i) {
            f[i] = new float[m_cols];
          }
          for (int i = 0; i < m_rows; ++i)
          {
            std::memcpy(f[i], iv.f[i], sizeof(float)*m_cols);
          }
          sum = iv.sum;
}
```